# Accessing datetime.now() values in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, while-loop, timedelta

I want to be able to implement a condition in my program where it would only run for N number of hours, maybe the user could specify N, but let's not jump ahead.

I figured I could use `datetime.now()`  and store the value below in a variable, `time`

```
>>> time 
>>> time = datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 9, 21, 50, 32, 405329)
```

Any ideas on how I can access the fourth field between the (--), seeing as it's a string?

My condition would be something like `while time != timeEnd` where timeEnd would be the value of below:

`>>> timeEnd = datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 9, 21+N, 50, 32, 405329)`

Thanks

Comment: What `--` are you talking about?

Comment: Are you being pedantic?

Comment: You don't want to do date/time math examining just the hour field -- you could easily terminate at (3 hours + 1 minute) or (5 hours - 1 minute), or if some tasks are very long-running, could even span days by mistake.  Use a time delta of some kind as the answers below suggest.

Comment: @adampski: No, I don't understand what you're talking about at all. Either you're asking about a literal `--` somewhere, in which case there is no such thing, or you're using it as a placeholder for a string that exists somewhere in your example, in which case there is _still_ no such thing; there aren't any strings visible anywhere.

Comment: @abarnet OK well (--) refers to the properties of the datetime object. Just couldn't believe to write them all out, it was a short-hand expressions of all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `timedelta` to a `datetime` to get a new `datetime`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> end_time = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
>>> print now
2013-12-09 17:03:06.979628
>>> print end_time
2013-12-09 23:03:06.979628
>>>
```

Then...

```
while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time:
    pass # do work
```

Comment: `datetime.now() < end_time` might not give your `6` hours. It may happen an hour sooner/later (due to DST) or any other amount of time if computer clock were manually adjusted. Or if computer were suspended for sometime; you might not want all events happen at once when you open notebook cover. [You can avoid such issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20529909/4279)

Answer (score 6):

Don't use unaware local datetime objects such as returned by `now()` unless you want to show them to a local user. [There are many perils](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/4279).

There is a [difference between "What time is it?" and "How many seconds elapsed?"](http://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/epochtime.html). The former is easier to find out.

To run for `N` hours, you could:

```
from time import monotonic as timer # or time.time if it is not available

endtime = timer() + N * 3600
while timer() < endtime:
    # do your thing (mind what clocks use sleep(), join(), lock.acquire())
```

It works even if computer time has changed during the program execution manually or due to DST transition. See [`Rational` section from pep-418 for introducing `time.monotonic` in Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#rationale).

You can choose other timers depending on your needs/available systems. For example, you could use a timer that provides better precision but might overflow sooner or that takes into account NTP adjacements that might provide better clock than your local CPU or [the time while the system were asleep or suspended](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#monotonic-clocks) (imagine what do you want to happen after you open the cover of your notebook after several hours).

`datetime.now()` object (naive broken-down time) might be useful if you want something happen at some local time regardless of how many seconds passed since now e.g., to do something after `7pm` whatever day (before midnight):

```
from datetime import datetime, time

if datetime.now().time() > time(19):
   # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.now()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 9, 23, 0, 20, 669780)
>>> d.hour
23
```

If you want to check whether script is running for `N` hours, I'd suggest checking the `(now() - start_time).total_seconds()` value. It'd tell you for how many seconds the script has been running.

Likewise, you can set the `timeEnd` like so `timeEnd = time + timedelta(hours=N)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to implement a condition in my program where it would only run for N number of hours, maybe the user could specify N, but let's not jump ahead.

…

> Any ideas on how I can access the fourth field between the (--), seeing as it's a string?

I don't see any `--` in your code, or any strings. You've got a `datetime` object, and it has an `hour` member. However, I can't imagine how you'd use such a thing in your code anyway.

Just subtract two `datetime` objects, and you get back a `timedelta` object. And you can compare that `timedelta` object to another one. For example:

```
>>> start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# 2 hours later

>>> end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> duration = end_time - start_time
>>> duration > datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
False

# another 4 hours

>>> datetime.datetime.now() - start_time > datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
True
```

Comment: Didn't realise it was an object. Sorry! Thank you.